# UITextView doesn't keep subviews visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextview

I'm implementing the a `viewController` to enter text and images (very similar to Facebook's "Status" entry) and I have most of it complete, however, the last piece isn't working correctly.

The user can select an image and key-in textual data.  As more text are added, the images get pushed down.  I implemented this by adding `UIImageView` as subview of `UIView`, then add `UIView` as subview of `UITextView`. They stack up like this:

- Top:    UIImageView
- Middle: UIView
- Bottom: UITextView

When I key-in long enough text that it pushes the images down, the images do not stay visible inside the `UITextView`.  I can still see the images if I drag the screen-up, but as soon as I let go, the images bounces down and can't be seen.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

[image: UITextView doesn't keep subview visible]

Answer (score 1):

You do the followings for this.

```
1- Have a UIimageView and set your image
2- Draw your UITextview on exact location of image. Means (x,y,w,h) equals
3-Set UItextView background color CLEAR.
```

and CHEERS

Comment: the images are shown on my simulator just fine.  As described, the images get slowly pushed down the screen as I type more and more text. Eventually, the images would be off the screen and I can only see them if I click and drag the screen up.  If I let go of my click, the images bounces off the screen.